# Is it possible to change the allocation area of automatic variables in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, stack, local-variables

This is a theoretical question for both C and C++.

I have a 4x4 matrix type which is defined quite simply as:

```
typedef float   Matrix44[16];
```

I also have many methods which take a `Matrix44` as a parameter, for example:

```
bool matrixIsIdentity(Matrix44 m);
```

I also have a custom memory allocation scheme in place whereby a large area of memory is pre-allocated on the heap and then I manage allocations on that prefetched memory manually. As such I have replaced/overloaded `malloc`/`new` with my own implementations. The problem is, both custom `malloc` and `new`, by nature, return a pointer, not an object.

Ordinarily, I would simply do the following:

```
   // Method 1
1] Matrix44 mat = { ... };
2] bool res = matrixIsIdentity(mat);
```

However, line 1 allocated `mat` on the stack, not in my custom memory area as I would wish. An alternative is:

```
    // Method 2
1]  Matrix44 *mmat = myMalloc(...);
1a] Matrix44 *nmat = new ...
2]  bool res = matrixIsIdentity(*mat);
```

The issue here is that I would have to litter my code with dereference operators. Now one option would be to rewrite all the methods to take `Matrix44*` instead, but, as this is theoretical, I would like to assume that is not an option.

Therefore my question becomes: Is there a way to declare an automatic variable in C and/or C++ as in `Method 1 Line 1`, but have it follow an alternate allocation scheme (as in `Method 2 Line 1`)?

(*I appreciate this may involve compiler-related discussion but I have not added tags to that effect*)

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but I sure hope it's not possible. If it doesn't look like a pointer, it shouldn't behave like a pointer. Of course, in C++ things aren't always so clear-cut, heh.

Comment: I guess that it, first of all, depends on the OS you are using. I guess you could fiddle with the linker in order to rearrange the memory layout. But I am far from being sure...

Comment: You really shouldn't take `Matrix44` as a parameter; it's very expensive. Declare such parameters a `const Matrix44&` instead. Would this perhaps reduce your desire to allocate matrices on the heap in the first place?

Comment: You could use references to your objects: Matrix44 &mmat = *myMalloc(...);

Comment: @bash.d, how do you fiddle with the linker to re-arrange the memory layout?  the stack frame, stack, etc. are all built into the compiler.  when you do *Matrix44 a;*, the compiler reserves space on the stack for *a*.  All of this is done *before* linking.  Just like the OP, I am curious if there is a trick around this.  The standard certainly doesn't define the stack...

Comment: @thang Thanks, and this is why I said, that I am not sure...

Comment: @infact, but then who frees the memory?

Comment: but it defines stack unwinding :) Automatic storage just meant to have stack behavior, so stack is used everywhere. It is deep inside the language(ctors/dtors order etc.). I can't imagine that anybody tries to implement automatic storage in structure different from stack.

Comment: @thang WHO or HOW? How: you just take the address: free(&mmat); Who: Well that's the problem you get when you're not using std::auto_ptr or similar.

Comment: @infact, yeah could work, but seems like a memory leak waiting to happen to me...

Comment: @thang the compiler is responsible for creating the code, but the linker eventually resolves symbols to addresses. So you could determine that using the linker. Look at [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103673/what-are-linkers-and-loaders-how-do-they-work).

Comment: @bash.d, but the stack frame and local variables are not symbols.  how do you fiddle with the linker to push stack variables into the heap?  and more over, make sure they're freed when you go out of scope?

Comment: @thang about pushing stack variables onto the heap, I agree, this sounds odd. I'll do some research on that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible, automatic variables are stack based. But you can do whatever you want inside the constructor. So your Matrix44 will be just a thin wrapper around, say,  Matrix44Impl which will point to your "custom" memory.

Comment: Actually they are allocated in automatic storage which can be whatever, but yes, most of the times that's the stack.

Comment: @sharptooth, i am curious where the *most of the times* comes from as it implies that there are some instances in which the stack is not used.  do you know of a compiler that does not use the stack to implement this?

Comment: @thang It depends on your defihition of "stack".  The C++ standard more or less requires automatic variables to be allocated on *A* stack, but not all hardware has a hardware stack, and a lot of people confuse the two.

Comment: @JamesKanze, the specific question I raised was *do you know of a compiler that does not use the stack to implement this?* with *this* meaning the automatic variables.  where in the standard does it require automatic variables be allocated on a stack?  but now that you bought it up, which hardware doesn't have a hardware stack?  so three questions now.  1.  which compiler doesn't use a stack to implement automatic store? 2.  which machine architecture doesn't have a hardware stack at all? 3.  where in the standard does it require automatic variables be allocated on a stack?

Comment: by the way, not trying to be argumentative.  i really want to know.

Comment: @thang: No, I don't know of any actual example.

Comment: @thang Most architectures don't have a hardware stack.  IBM mainframes for example, and most Risc architectures.  Of course, once you have some sort of indirect addressing and can do arithmetic operations on a register, using a register as a stack pointer is rather trivial.  But the compiler has to generate the code to do so.  As for the standard, the entire scoping and lifetime rules obey a stack protocol, as does the fact that you can call functions recursively.  (How the stack is implemented is another question---I recall one compiler which malloced each stack frame.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not 100% exactly what you ask for, but using a reference will *look like* what you want, and behave more or less indistinguishable from what you want, if I understand correctly:

```
Matrix44& mmat = *new Matrix44(...);   // or *myMalloc() or whatever

mmat.Rotate(45.0);
bool res = matrixIsIdentity(mat);
...
delete &mmat; // or myFree(&mmat) or something similar
```

Note the dereference on `new`, and address-of operator on `delete` which is admittedly a bit queer, but I don't see why it would be syntactically/semantically wrong. The compiler accepts it just fine too, and it "works".

I would strongly advise against doing such a thing, though. Even if it "works" perfectly well, it is misleading. Code should look like what it's doing, and it should do what it looks like. This code doesn't.

Something that *looks like* it lives on the stack shouldn't be required (or, even possible!) to be handed to `delete`, and arguably code that does something queer does not really "work" even if it "works fine".